# Auto-Update Layers in ArcCatalog from modified layers from .DWG

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog

let's say that we have 2 layers in autocad .dwg : 
1 layer specify the roads and 1 layer specify buldings.

Now if we create in ArcCatalog (Import-> Feature class single..) and load the .dwg and creating a layer (polyline) with name "Buildings" is any option after creating the polyline to be modified (auto-updated) if we will add more buildings in the .dwg file?

P.S actually i delete the layer (polyline) in arccatalog and recreate them from scratch.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anyway to dynamically link to any data stored in a CAD drawing.

However, using AutoCAD Map or Civil 3D you can connect to a spatial dataset such a shapefile or a PostGIS table and work on that data in AutoCAD.

Unfortunately I no longer have access to AutoCAD Civil 3D to provide screenshots but here is the page on AutoDesks Help website detailing how to add GIS data to AutoCAD Map: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/MAP3D-Learn/files/GUID-BD9DBAC6-B6B8-4665-A55B-FAD893C1531B-htm.html

The command used to be Map Connect, but it looks like with newer releases it's being called Data Connect.